# Display dynamic popup content in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, popup, contact-form-7

I've got a contact form (cf7) that users fill out, and I'd like to have a popup that displays upon form submission (I've got this part down already) and displays a variable body of content depending on the user's selected item in a dropdown box. I'm currently using **wppopupmaker**, and I haven't been able to figure out how I could achieve this end with what I've got.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

create a bootstrap modal popup then add this function in function.php

```
<?php add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer' );
function mycustom_wp_footer() {
?>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
         if ( '34' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { // Change 123 to the ID of the form 
         jQuery('#myModal2').modal('show'); //this is the bootstrap modal popup id
       }
        }, false );
         </script>
       <?php  } ?>
```

**OR**

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', function ($cf7) {
    // Run code after the email has been sent
 $wpcf = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
$wpccfid=$wpcf->id;
    // if you wanna check the ID of the Form $wpcf->id
     if ( '34' == $wpccfid ) { // Change 123 to the ID of the form 
echo '
 <div class="modal fade in formids" id="myModal2" role="dialog" style="display:block;" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content no_pad text-center">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <div class="modal-header heading">
          <h3 class="modal-title">Message Sent!</b></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="thanku_outer define_float text-center">
                <h3>Thank you for getting in touch!</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    </div>
';
    }
});
```

Comment: How do you know they're using bootstrap?

Comment: @HowardE model is load in bootstrap